# VB.NET Boxing weirdness

Tags: vb.net

I can't understand what is happening with the following code in VB.NET.  When I run this code:

```
Public Function test() As Boolean
    Dim  a As Integer = 1
    Dim b As Object = a
    Dim c As Object = b
    Return Object.ReferenceEquals(b, c)
End Function
```

Then the function returns `True`.  However, if I run this:

```
Structure TTest
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tid As Integer
    Sub New(ByVal _i As Integer, ByVal _tid As Integer)
        i = _i
        tid = _tid
    End Sub
End Structure

Public Function test_2() As Boolean
    Dim a As New TTest(1, 1)
    Dim b As Object = a
    Dim c As Object = b
    Return Object.ReferenceEquals(b, c)
End Function
```

Then it returns `False`.  In both functions, I declare two value type variables, an `Integer` on the first and a custom `Structure` on the second one.  Both should be boxed upon object assignment, but in the second example, it seems to get boxed into two different objects, so `Object.ReferenceEquals` returns `False`.

Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 1):

For primitive types, .Net is able to re-use the same "box" for the same values, and thus improve performance by reducing allocations.

Comment: So there's no way to have a unique reference to a value type even boxing to an object ? The problem is i have to assign a custom type to a buffer of objects , in a multithreaded environment using a lock-free queue and to assign it i'm using Interlockes.CompareExchange , but to check the result i have to compare the original object to the one assigned , which fails in case of custom value types like structures .

Comment: It only does this for primitives. For the value compare... override .Equals() and .GetHashCode()

Comment: I don't need to compare values , i need to compare memory reference of values ...... Interlocked.CompareExchange does not return the status of the operation ( if succeded or not ) so the only way to check this is to compare reference of object to be modified with desired result value .

Comment: This is one reason to prefer classes rather than structs.

Answer (score 0):

Same with strings, it's .NET way to optimize thing. But as soon as you use it, the reference will change.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim a As String = "abc"
    Dim b As String = "abc"

    Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) ' True

    b = "123"

    Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) ' False

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: True, but boxed object reference does not change . in my example , if i change integer to string and before  doing ...Dim c as object = b
... i re-assign a still referencecompare returns true

Comment: @dreamprisoner yes because "a" will be given a new reference. b and c will point to the old integer.